# Tell phpcs to use a different indent inside control structures

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, psr-12

Output of `phpcs` is telling me to put 8 spaces inside the `if`

```
class bla
{
  private function wop()
  {
    if (true) {
      $something = 'yes'; // 6 spaces indent is what I want!
    }
  }
}
```

> indented at least once; expected at least 8 spaces, but found 6
> (PSR12.ControlStructures.ControlStructureSpacing.LineIndent) Each line in a
> multi-line control structure must be

How do I tell `phpcs` that I prefer 6 spaces?

Comment: You can have PSR-12 or you can have 2-space indentation, but not both: "Code MUST use an indent of 4 spaces for each indent level, and MUST NOT use tabs for indenting." ([Source](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#24-indenting))

Comment: Ah, I guess that explains why there's no setting.

Comment: @klokop: There is a setting, but the PSR-12 set configures it for four spaces, you want to configure it with two spaces. You can create your own configuration inheriting existing style(s) and then just overriding with your changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation size is [part of PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#24-indenting) so it isn't possible to fine-tune it if you want to comply with that coding style:

> ### 2.4 Indenting
>
> Code MUST use an indent of 4 spaces for each indent level, and MUST
> NOT use tabs for indenting.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I tell `phpcs` that I prefer 6 spaces?

Look into the default rules that ship with phpcs itself. There is an easy system where you can pick and play with every single rule and their parameters.

A large set of them are so called [*Customisable Sniff Properties*](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Customisable-Sniff-Properties) and from the Sniff you'd like to tailor — PSR12 — and the name of the rule in the violation — PSR12.ControlStructures.ControlStructureSpacing.LineIndent — we have the educated guess that it is the **indent** property of **[PSR12.ControlStructures.ControlStructureSpacing](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Customisable-Sniff-Properties#psr12controlstructurescontrolstructurespacing)**.

> One of the rules that this sniff enforces is the indent of each condition in a control structure when the conditions have been split over multiple lines. By default, this sniff ensures that the conditions are indented 4 spaces, but you can change the size of the `indent` by setting the indent property. [*[src](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Customisable-Sniff-Properties#psr12controlstructurescontrolstructurespacing)*]

To have your configuration with your project, [I'd recommend using a default configuration file](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#using-a-default-configuration-file).

In general, IIRC, there is one folder with many standard whitespace rules, it should be re-using the existing rule for the indent and setting your preference of six spaces via parameters (these are XML Documents).

Btw. the whitespace handling is pretty superior in `phpcs`/`phpcbf`, I've not seen any other tooling that came close. However, this may mean you'd need to tweak more than one parameter/rule/sniff.

YMMV, so please let me know if this information was already helpful, otherwise ask in comments for further clarifications.